# Why is a bracket '{' an unexpected token when trying to import in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to use Facebook's fixed-data-table module, simply following the basic example on this page:
https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

However, I am getting the following error when I try to use webpack to bundle my files using 'npm run prod', which runs 'npm webpack -p':

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({) [./app/index.js:1,0]
```

These is only one line in index.js:

```
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
```

This is what my package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "datatables",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.3",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.0"
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to get the basic example code working. Thanks.

edit: add webpack:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});
var CssWebpack = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/fixed-data-table.css',
    filename: 'fixed-data-table.css',
    inject: 'head'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./app/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: 'node -v' returns 'v6.4.0', and 'npm -v' returns '3.10.3'

Comment: Do you have import statements elsewhere in your code? I can't remember if `babel-preset-react` is enough.. you may need other presets like `stage-3` or something specific with import. Can you post your webpack config file as well?

Comment: just added the config file, there are no other imports, the only js file is the index.js and everything else is commented out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node doesn't currently support import statements. Should just have to add the presets to your webpack loader configuration and it will transpile properly

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react

module: {
    loaders: [
        { 
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
},
```

Comment: I think I did not have "es2015" in my .babelrc file, but upon adding it all was well (I did not have to add it as a preset to the webpack). Thank you for pointing out es2015!